# How does one prove NFT ownership?

Tags: gas, nft

I've been hearing a lot about [nft](/questions/tagged/nft) and I understand some fundamentals, though I am not 100% clear how would one prove ownership of an NFT token.

Does proving NFT ownership requires to pay [gas](/questions/tagged/gas) fees?

Comment: It discusses a similar question, though I don't believe it answers it. I understand how to check who the owner is of NFT. The part that I don't understand is how do I check that the person who claims to be the owner of NFT actually owns the wallet. Maybe a better question then is how do I prove that someone owns a specific ETH address.

Comment: The standard way to prove address ownership is to sign a message with the private key.